# change color of ColdFusion comments and tags within ColdFusion comments with Visual Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, coldfusion

I currently have this in settings which does this trick when the comments are just text

```
        {
            "scope": "comment.block.cfml",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#f5cd76"
            }
        }
```

However if there are tags then the tags use their default color. I can see for a split second that the color of all the comment block is correct which tells me that something is overwrite it?

This is what it does

[image: What it does]

What i want it to do

[image: What i want it to do]

Answer (score 3):

You could install the CFML package for VSCode.  (Assuming that's what you meant by Visual Code.)  It identifies all the "parts" of statements and triggers what's needed, generally.  Never had an issue.  (Though I have had an issue with it using script comments (//) instead of the markup comments <!--- --->.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
            "scope": "comment",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#f5cd76"
            }
        }
```

this seemed to of worked